# Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix of rank $1$ and $G$ be an $n \times m$ matrix such that $AGA = A$. Show that the trace of $AG$ is $1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Q.
Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix of rank $1$ and $G$ be an $n \times m$ matrix such
that $AGA = A$. Show that the trace of $AG$ is $1$.

Here is an argument

rank$(A) = 1$ implies that $A$ can be written as a product of a column vector $u$ of size $m$ and a row vector $v$ of size $n$, i.e., $A = uv$.

$\operatorname{trace} AB = \operatorname{trace} BA$ for any matrices $A$ and $B$.

Now

$AGA = A
\Rightarrow AGuv = uv
\Rightarrow (AG)u(v^{T} u) = uv
\Rightarrow (AG)u = v$

So

$\operatorname{trace} AG = \operatorname{trace} AGuu^{T}$ (since $uu^{T}$ is a matrix of rank $1$)
$= \operatorname{trace} u^TAGu
= \operatorname{trace} u^Tvu
= v^T u
= 1$ (since $A = uv$ and $v^T u = 1$)

Therefore, $\operatorname{trace} AG=1$

Please check this...also you can give another solution...

Comment: I think it would be helpful to write $uv^T$ instead of $uv$. Further: I don't understand the implication: $AGuv=uv \Rightarrow (AG)u(v^Tu)=uv$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could begin with
$$uv^TGuv^T=uv^T$$
and applying trace() on both sides with some rearrangement:
$$\text{tr}(v^Tuv^TGu)=v^Tu$$
$v^Tu$ is a scalar and can be pulled out, therefore:
$$v^Tu\text{tr}(v^TGu)=v^Tu$$
In the end, we have (assuming $v^Tu\neq 0$):
$$\text{tr}(AG)=\text{tr}(GA)=\text{tr}(Guv^T)=1$$
It could be that the case $v^Tu= 0$ needs additional treatment.